# How do I move a code block to the left on SO?

Tags: support, code-formatting

Just wondering: Is there a key-combination for moving code blocks left (inverted tab)?
<kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd> doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Clicking the code block icon seems to do just that when you paste code which is inverted to the right. Each click removing one tab from the beginning of each line...

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to add shift + tab to the editor?

Comment: `Ctrl + K` will indent/unindent code blocks.

Comment: There's no way to do it... I often paste the code in an IDE or something like JsFiddle (which allow shift + tab) in order to reindent

Comment: @HugoDozois If there's no way to do it, would it be a valid `feature-request`?

Comment: I would upvote that as I'd like to have that

Comment: @Rob A valid request, probably. But a duplicate one, I think. I'm not good at searching, and too lazy to do now, but I'm almost sure I remember the tab key being made usable for code indetation/unindentation being requested before.

Answer (score 4):

Select the code, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or click on `{}` icon  to format it as code and click again (while text is selected) for undo.

Comment: Well it's not an equivalent of the shift + tab behavior..

Comment: @Rob - Can you format your text as code by pressing `tab`?