# Enable tab and shift + tab for code formatting

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

After some discussion on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174958/how-do-i-move-a-code-block-to-the-left-on-so/174960?noredirect=1#comment523774_174960) question I decided to make a feature-request (or at least a discussion about it).

It would be very nice to be able to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move code blocks (like in any major IDE).

The most important reason for this request/discussion is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> does not give the desired result/behavior.

Looking forward to your opinions on this.

Comment: Because you are not really supposed to editing code on the site.. Only posting it. Write it and format it in your favorite IDE and just paste it into the post...

Comment: So, it's OK to break normal tabbing in the browser (links, form elements etc)?

Comment: I'm in favor of this. As long as it's only in the question/answer text field.

Comment: @Lix What a due respect, but i do spend quite a lot of time on SO editing anwers because people fail to post it correctly..

Comment: I support this! This is so useful

Comment: I'm not dedicated enough to open up an IDE just to fix a random person's code indentation.

Comment: How about the best of both worlds - have it off by default, but include a checkbox "Allow Tabs to format code".

Comment: No, please don't highjack the `tab` key.  It already has a well-established use in the browser.  Fix `Ctrl+K` and add `Ctrl+Shift+K` (or other shortcut keys) instead.

Comment: @acutesoftware actually the tab button could be inserting 4 spaces as it does in many IDE, or as it does in JsFiddle.

Comment: @BilltheLizard that would also be acceptable.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I guess that sounds fair, it's just annoying that `Ctrl` and `K` are not one-handish :P

Comment: @rob - what about using the right (as opposed to left) Ctrl button? That makes it very one-handish :P

Comment: I have a related Feature-Request on MSO: [Can we get a button in the post editor to toggle the Tab key being used as 4 Spaces?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158344/158605)

Comment: @Lix Yeah, but i'm right-handed. So my right hand would be on my mouse :)

Comment: @rob - tisk tisk... *Real programmers* never leave the home row ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard - I think the current feature is perfect [(pressing `Ctrl + K` again to undo code format)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174960/187824)

Comment: @juh - the assumption is that as a programmer at a computer, assisting people on a programmers Q&A site, that you would have an IDE of some sort already open... Also you seem dedicated enough to get a gold badge for your editing contributions :P

Comment: @hims056 I think it could be better. Press `Ctrl + K` again to indent more, `Ctrl + Shift + K` to undo one level of indent.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Yeh I would be better idea! [See the users pain](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148385/why-does-indenting-this-code-4-spaces-not-work/148387#comment-426614)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I never use Ctrl+K because I typically have my right hand on my mouse, and my left hand on the left side of the keyboard, while the `K` key is on the right side of my keyboard. It would be much easier to use if whatever shortcut key is used is on the right side of the keyboard.

Comment: @Rachel I think they picked `Ctrl + K` because most of the left-hand keys already have a default shortcut setting in most browsers.  If they can find some other shortcut that's not used I'd be fine with it.  (Even just adding "indent more" and "indent less" buttons in the formatting row above the editor window would be fine with me.  I can use the mouse.)

Comment: I'd be down for having a checkbox or a user setting to force it to use the tab key. I'm sure many people like me never use the tab for its default purpose.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n "I'm sure many people like me never use the tab for its default purpose" - you're right, I sometimes have to watch them use their computers and it's *painful* ;)

Comment: @AakashM To me, painful is tabbing 20 times to select a DOM element that I could reach with a scroll and a click. But to each his own.

Comment: "[Or other shortcut keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234662/should-shift-spacebar-create-a-tab-indent-in-se)" @BilltheLizard

Comment: GitHub is handling tab shift-tab (un)indentation for a while without any problem. I would like to have this feature when editing mal formatted code indentation (sometimes I copy/paste code in my editor, fix indentation then copy code back to SO.. very painful)

Answer (score 8):

Though this is not a native StackExchange feature, there's a user script on StackApps that does exactly what you are looking for:

[**Better handling of indentation and the TAB key when editing posts**](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts)

> This user script changes the behavior of a few keys (most notably the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key) within the post editor to behave more like it does in IDEs or text editors:
>
> - When multiple lines are selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> indent and dedent these lines
> - When nothing is selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> insert or remove whitespace to align the cursor on a tab boundary
> - When the cursor is within the left margin of a line, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> removes whitespace to align the cursor on a tab boundary (in other words, it may delete more than just one space character)
> - On indented lines, the <kbd>Home</kbd> key toggles the cursor between the *actual* beginning of the line and the beginning of the real content (in other words, it jumps back and forth to before and after the leading whitespace). This only happens on lines that are indented by at least four spaces or a tab, since it can be confusing for the following reason: When you press <kbd>Home</kbd> in the text editor, you expect the cursor to jump to the beginning of the line *as it is displayed*, which (due to wrapping) may be different from the actual previous newline character.
> - So you don't have to reach for the mouse to tab out of the editor you can press *and release* the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and the next key press will not be intercepted; thus <kbd>Tab</kbd> takes you out of the editor. Pressing and releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will grey out the text editor until the next keystroke to clarify this. If you think this is too awkward, I'm open to other suggestions, but there should be some way to tab out of the editor .
>
> Note that this will never insert TAB characters, only spaces. It does however handle already-present TABs, and it handles them the same way the Markdown converter does.

Answer (score 0):

A "format code" tool would imply

1. knowing how to format many different languages
2. picking a indentation style

The first is a hassle, the second an invitation to holy wars.

You shouldn't be typing significant bits of code directly into SO anyway, as you *will* generate spurious errors: *cut and paste the code that you ran* to show how it doesn't do what you hoped.

Format in your editor or IDE, already.

Answer (score 0):

[As has been said before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/493/improvements-to-editor-for-formatting-source-code/1076#1076), if you make <kbd>Tab</kbd> indent instead of moving between fields, **you are breaking a fundamental UI feature**. Please don't do this. Make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> indent instead. Yes, it's less discoverable, but it beats breaking moving between fields. The problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is that it only supports a single level (which breaks in lists, in particular) — so fix that. Do not change the functionality of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Comment: Note that GitHub is handling (un)indentation with Tab and Shift+Tab for a while now and without any accessibility issue (because only when text is selected). This is now kind of a keyboard shortcut "standard".